# Use non quantified deeplab model on coral board

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

I use a quantified model of deeplab v3 on coral dev board. The result is not really precise so I want to use a non quantified model.

I can find a tflite non quantified model of deeplab so I want to generate it.
I donwload a xception65_coco_voc_trainval model on Tensorflow github:
[xception65_coco_voc_trainval](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md)

Then I use that command to tranform the input:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph="/path/to/xception65_coco_voc_trainval.pb" \
--out_graph="/path/to/xception65_coco_voc_trainval_flatten.pb" \
--inputs='ImageTensor' \
--outputs='SemanticPredictions' \
--transforms='
    strip_unused_nodes(type=quint8, shape="1,513,513,3")
    flatten_atrous_conv
    fold_constants(ignore_errors=true, clear_output_shapes=false)
    fold_batch_norms
    fold_old_batch_norms
    remove_device
    sort_by_execution_order
```

Then I generate the tflite file with this command:

```
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file="/tmp/deeplab_mobilenet_v2_opt_flatten_static.pb" \
  --output_file="/tmp/deeplab_mobilenet_v2_opt_flatten_static.tflite" \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shape=1,513,513,3 \
  --input_arrays="ImageTensor" \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=true \
  --output_arrays="SemanticPredictions" \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

This command generates me a tflite file. I donwload the file on my coral dev board and I try to run it with.

I use that example on github to try my deeplab model on coral:
[deeplab on coral](https://github.com/NobuoTsukamoto/edge_tpu/blob/master/deeplab/python/deeplab_videocapture.py)

When I start the program there is an error:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

The error comes from that line:

```
engine = BasicEngine(args.model)
```